# Swipe left/right event on mobile devices, like a "click"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need help:
I have a classic carousel with arrow next and arrow prev for the images; I need to change the event like a click, in an event for switch next or prev image.

This:

```
$('.next-arrow").click(function({
    //Move the carousel to the next photo
})

$('.prev-arrow").click(function({
    //Move the carousel to the prev photo
})
```

Like this:

```
$('.mycarousel").svipe on right (function({
    //Move the carousel to the next photo
})

$('.mycarousel").svipe on left(function({
    //Move the carousel to the prev photo
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look for [jQuery mobile swipe event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a hammer.js - https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/. Seems like it has what you're looking for.